# How to print interactive certificate in flash action script 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i am new in action script 2. How to get input text from user in first slide and then print on interactive certificate in the end of flash slide show.

Answer (score 0):

well.. you use the text field, set the type to "input text" and set it's name to something, like "user_name".

after the user inputs his username/clicks some button you access the text via user_name.text. so you could do `_root.user_name=user_name.text`. (an ugly way to do it, but very simple and effective for a beginner).

when you want to show this information, you use "dynamic textfield" this time (called final_text for example) and set the name like this: `final_text.text=_root.user_name;`

i have used relative paths to the textfields' parent holders, of course. anyways, it's really hard to answer more specifically as we don't know:

- any names of the movieclips
- where are they located
- how is the presentation/input switch triggered
- do you have any code?
- do you know any actionscript at all?
- etc etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have done it with a help of friend. He did it by urs guide.